# Network communication is blocked by IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I have a client server application which the client side is running on web-browser, in this case IE11. The application would connect to the server side which listen on TCP port 59082.

During TLS handshake sequence, it seems it is blocked in the middle of the handshake. However, if I press the F12 to activate the dev-tools, the network communication would continue.

Using WireShark, I captured the network communication. Here where it is blocked:

[image]

The network communication stopped there. Once I pressed F12, it will continue to this part (see step 15 and so on):

[image]

I have no idea how to investigate this because F12 would fix the problem. And the same application works fine on Google Chrome.

Anyone has idea what to check?

Comment: It is so strange, you could try resetting the IE browser setting and check whether you have enabled the TLS (In the Internet options, select the Advanced tab, then enable the related TLS options). Here are some related articles, you could check them: [SSL/TLS - Typical problems and how to debug them](https://maulwuff.de/research/ssl-debugging.html#hdr2.1) and [Troubleshooting TLS / SSL communication problems when making HTTP web request in ASP.NET Part 2](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/IIS-Support-Blog/Troubleshooting-TLS-SSL-communication-problems-when-making-HTTP/ba-p/481296).

Comment: That part is not the problem. TLS 1.x is supported. You see, the TLS itself is not the problem, once I pressed F12, everything works. As you can see in the WireShark capture, the protocol used was TLS 1.2. And Windows Firewall is turned off. I did reset IE11 settings, that didn't help.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Please try to produce the issue using some other machine with IE to find that whether that specific machine has any issue or not. Can you the IE browser version? Besides, please check your JavaScript code, whether it contains some debugging code (such as: `console.log()`), if contains, try to remove it.